# Does HTTP Content Negotiation apply to error messages?

Tags: rest, http, restful-architecture, content-negotiation, http-accept-header

If a client sends an Accept header of application/xml, should the body of any error message (e.g. 500) also be xml? Or does the Accept header only apply to 200-level responses?

Answer (score 0):

These sources imply that Content Negotiation should apply to error messages.

[API Error Codes](http://apiux.com/2013/03/28/2-steps-api-error-codes/) – 
*The payload format can change according to what MIME types your API uses: you might reply with a JSON payload including your specific error code and an optional error message, or with an XML body with similar information.*

[Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) – 
*When the Twitter API returns error messages, it does so in your requested format.*

Comment: Twitter has changed their API. It now states, "_Twitter API error messages are returned in JSON format._"